# Add dummy data to mySql Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'graph' with the fields id, date, value.

This query (dateStart and dateFinish are defined by me):

```
SELECT id, date, value FROM graph WHERE date BETWEEN dateStart AND dateFinish
```

Returns this result:

```
id     | date                   | value
id0    | 2017-10-01 00:01:23    | 13
id1    | 2017-11-01 00:06:03    | 10
...    | ...                    | ...
id0    | 2017-15-01 00:05:33    | 34
id1    | 2017-14-01 00:21:23    | 19
```

I need to duplicate the first and last rows of each ID with date value as dateStart and dateFinish, so the results look like this:

```
id     | date                   | value
id0    | dateFirst              | 13
id1    | dateFirst              | 10
id0    | 2017-10-01 00:01:23    | 13
id1    | 2017-11-01 00:06:03    | 10
...    | ...                    | ...
id0    | 2017-15-01 00:05:33    | 34
id1    | 2017-14-01 00:21:23    | 19
id0    | dateFinish             | 34
id1    | dateFinish             | 19
```

In short, i need to duplicate the first and last row of each id.

The reason for this requirement is that we're using an external library, where the only parameter required is a query, so i can't touch the results after the query, which is why I'm looking for a pure mySQL solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
SELECT id, date, value
FROM graph
WHERE date BETWEEN v_dateStart AND v_dateFinish
UNION ALL
SELECT id, v_dateStart, value
FROM graph g
WHERE g.date = (SELECT MIN(g2.date) FROM graph g2 WHERE g2.id = g.id)
UNION ALL
SELECT id, v_dateEnd, value
FROM graph g
WHERE g.date = (SELECT MAX(g2.date) FROM graph g2 WHERE g2.id = g.id);
```